# Does multithreading actually work in uniprocessor environment

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

Suppose we have a process with multiple threads in a uniprocessor.
Now I know that if we have several processes, only one of them will be processed at a time in a uniprocessor and hence the processes are not concurrent.
If my understanding is correct, similarly each thread will be processed at a time and not concurrent in a uniprocessor. Is this statement true? If so then does multithreading mean having more than one thread in a process and does not mean running multiple threads at a time? And does that mean there's no benefit of creating user threads in a uniprocessor environment?

Comment: "Concurrent" does not mean the same thing as "parallel."  Two function calls are _concurrent_ if both have been started before either one of them is finished.  They're still concurrent even if the single processor can only be working on one of them at any given instant in time.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: threads are switching more often than processes and in real time we have an effect of concurrency because it is happens really fast.

when you wrote:

> each thread will be processed at a time and not concurrent in a uni processor

Notice the word "concurrent", there is no real concurrency in uni processor, there is only effect of that thanks to the multiple number of context switches between processes.

Let's clarify something here, the single core of the CPU can handle one thread at a given time, each process has a main thread and (if needed) more threads running together. If a process A is now running and it has 3 threads: A1(main thread), A2, A3 all three will be running as long as process A is being processed by the CPU core. When a context switch occur process A is no longer running and now process B will run with his threads.

About this statement:

> there's no benefit of creating user threads in a uni processor environment

That is not true. there is a benefit in creating threads, they are easier to create ("spawn" as in the books) and shearing the process heap memory. Creating a sub process ("child" as in the books) is a overhead comparing to a thread because a process need to have his own memory. For example each google chrome tab is a process not a thread, but this tab has multiple threads running concurrency with little responsibility.

Comment: There can be real [concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) in a uni-processor environment.  What you don't have in that environment is _[parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing)_.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still somehow running a computer with just one, single-core, CPU, then you would be correct to observe that only one thread can be physically executing at one time. But that does not negate the value of breaking up the application into multiple threads and/or processes.

The essential benefit is ***concurrency***.  When one thread is waiting *(e.g. for an input/output operation to complete),* there is something else for the CPU to be doing in the meantime: it can be running a different thread that *isn't* waiting.  With a carefully designed application, you can get much better utilization of every part of the hardware, more parallelism, and thus, more throughput.

My favorite go-to example is a fast food restaurant.  About a dozen workers, each one doing different things, *cooperate* to bring your order to you.  Even if one of them (say, "the fry guy") is standing around, someone else always has something to do.  Several orders are in-process at once.  This *overlap,* this "concurrency," is what you are shooting for – regardless of how many CPUs you have.

Multithreading is also commonly used with GUI applications that also need to do some kind of "heavy lifting."  One thread handles the GUI interaction *(and has no other real responsibilities)* while other threads, with a slightly inferior *priority* (or "niceness") do the lifting. When a GUI event comes in, the GUI thread *pre-empts* the others and responds to it immediately, then of course goes right back to sleep again.  But in this way the GUI always remains very responsive – even though the other threads are doing "heavy lifting" things, GUI messages are still handled very promptly.  *(I scooped-up about a 25% performance improvement by re-tooling an older application to use this approach, because the application was no longer "polling" for GUI events.)*

Comment: Some of us are still writing code for single-CPU systems.  E.g., https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/nxp-usa-inc/OM13032598/568-8599-ND/2797414

Answer (score 1):

The first question I ask about any thread is, "what does it *wait* for?"  To me, a thread is defined by what *event* it waits for and what it does when that event happens.

Threads were in wide-spread use for at least a decade before multi-processor computers became commercially available. They are useful when you want to write a program that has to respond to un-synchronized events that come from multiple different sources.  There's a few different ways to model a program like that. One way is to have a different thread to wait on each different event source.  The next most popular is an [event driven architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) in which there's a main loop that waits for all events and calls different event handler functions for each of the different kinds of event.

The multi-threaded style of program often is easier to read* because there's usually different activities going on inside the program, and the state of each activity can be implicit in the *[context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_(computing))* (i.e., registers and call stack) of the thread that's driving it, while in the event-driven model, each activity's state must be explicitly encoded in some object.

The implicit-in-the-context way of keeping the state is much closer to the *[procedural style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming)* of coding a single activity that we learn as beginners.

---

*Easier to *read* does not mean that the code is easy to *write* without making bad and non-obvious mistakes!!

Answer (score 0):

The main impetus for developing threads was Ada compliance. Prior to that, different operating systems had their own ways of handing multiple things at once. In eunuchs, the way to do more than one thing was to spin off a new process. In VMS, software interrupts (aka Asynchronous System Traps or Asynchronous Procedure Calls in Windoze). In those days  (1970's) multiprocessor systems were rare.

One of the goals of Ada was to have a system independent way of doing things. It adopted the "task" which is effectively a thread. In order to support Ada, compiler developers had to include task (thread) libraries.

With the rise of multiprocessors, operating systems started to make threads (rather than processes) the basic schedulable unit in a system.

Threads then give a way for programs to handle multiple things simultaneously, even if there is only one processor. Sadly, support for threads in programming languages has been woefully lacking. Ada is the only major language I can think of that has real support for threads (tasks). Thread support in Java, for example, is a complete, sick joke. The result is threads are not as effective in practice as they could be.